# extração de nós via postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

É possível via comandos no Postgres tratar dados vetoriais. Eu tenho uma tabela com dados que representam o deslocamento de objetos e preciso extrair vertice final e inicial. Isso é possível via PostgreSQL?

Comment: Pode dar um exemplo de dado que quer trabalhar no PostgreSQL?

Comment: deslocamento de um veiculo em um centro urbano. Local de origem e destino de um trajeto diário.

Comment: considerando que esse trajeto seja representado por uma linha, eu poderia extrair vértices desse vetor via query no postgresql?

Answer (score 1):

**Resposta curta:** sim. Se você utilizar tipos de dados que suportem arrays, no Postgres você consegue extrair quaisquer elementos deles, qualquer que sejam suas posições. Agora vamos à resposta longa...

#### PostgreSQL sem extensões

Partindo do princípio que você está lidando com pontos de coordenadas geográficas como as extraídas de um GPS, e representa os seus dados como séries de pares latitude/longitude, em PostgreSQL "puro" pode armazená-los em [`arrays`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html) ou [`json`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/datatype-json.html). Ambos os métodos possibilitam a extração de itens arbitrários.

---

**Arrays**

Assim, uma série de posições geográficas como a seguinte, pega de um GPX aleatório aqui...

```
34.295944 132.319809
34.295971 132.319809
34.295998 132.320129
34.296024 132.319763
```

...pode ser representada como um *array* de *arrays* com pares de "floats":

```
ARRAY[
  [34.295944,  132.319809], [34.295971,  132.319809], 
  [34.295998,  132.320129], [34.296024,  132.319763]
]
```

Para obter o primeiro e último elementos do *array*, utilize as [funções dedicadas a array](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html) do Postgres:

```
with paths as (
 select ARRAY[
  [34.295944,  132.319809], [34.295971,  132.319809],
  [34.295998,  132.320129], [34.296024,  132.319763]
 ] as path
)
select path[1:1] as "primeiro", path[array_length(path, 1):] as "ultimo" from paths;
         primeiro         |          ultimo          
--------------------------+--------------------------
 {{34.295944,132.319809}} | {{34.296024,132.319763}}
(1 row)
```

Uma limitação do uso de *arrays* é a impossibilidade de criar estruturas de tipos de dados mistos. Um campo de tabela para conter os dados acima deveria ser declarado como *array* *numeric* de duas dimensões, sendo a segunda delimitada a dois elementos:

```
create table teste (path numeric(9,6)[][2]);
insert into teste values (ARRAY[
  [34.295944,  132.319809], [34.295971,  132.319809],
  [34.295998,  132.320129], [34.296024,  132.319763]
 ]);
select * from teste;
                                             path                                              
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 {{34.295944,132.319809},{34.295971,132.319809},{34.295998,132.320129},{34.296024,132.319763}}
(1 row)
```

---

**JSON**

O mesmo dado pode ser representado em *array* de objetos JSON do seguinte modo:

```
'[
  {"lat": 34.295944, "lon": 132.319809},
  {"lat": 34.295971, "lon": 132.319809},
  {"lat": 34.295998, "lon": 132.320129},
  {"lat": 34.296024, "lon": 132.319763}
]'::json
```

E, portanto, consultado com as [funções e operadores de manipulação de JSON](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html):

```
with paths as (
 select '[
  {"lat": 34.295944, "lon": 132.319809},
  {"lat": 34.295971, "lon": 132.319809},
  {"lat": 34.295998, "lon": 132.320129},
  {"lat": 34.296024, "lon": 132.319763}
 ]'::json as path
)
select path->0 as primeiro, path->json_array_length(path)-1 as ultimo from paths;
               primeiro                |                ultimo                 
---------------------------------------+---------------------------------------
 {"lat": 34.295944, "lon": 132.319809} | {"lat": 34.296024, "lon": 132.319763}
(1 row)
```

O uso de JSON é mais flexível do que o de *array*, visto suportar estruturas mistas de tipos de dados. Ambas as soluções suportam indexação, sobretudo campos de dados de tipo [jsonb](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/datatype-json.html#JSON-INDEXING). Basta criar uma coluna com o tipo de dados adequado e colocar dentro dela dados em JSON de qualquer tipo e tamanho:

```
create table teste (path jsonb);
insert into teste values ('[
  {"lat": 34.295944, "lon": 132.319809},
  {"lat": 34.295971, "lon": 132.319809},
  {"lat": 34.295998, "lon": 132.320129},
  {"lat": 34.296024, "lon": 132.319763}
 ]');
select * from teste;
                                                                             path                                                                             
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [{"lat": 34.295944, "lon": 132.319809}, {"lat": 34.295971, "lon": 132.319809}, {"lat": 34.295998, "lon": 132.320129}, {"lat": 34.296024, "lon": 132.319763}]
(1 row)
```

---

#### PostGIS

Dito tudo isso, para trabalhos sérios de geoprocessamento você pode também utilizar a extensão [PostGIS](http://www.postgis.net/), que [oferece](http://www.postgis.net/docs/manual-2.4/reference.html#PostGIS_Types) tipos de dados, funções, índices e outros objetos específicos para esse tipo de tarefa. Uma funcionalidade interessante para o seu caso pode ser a capacidade de [interpolar](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.4/ST_Line_Interpolate_Point.html) um ponto ao longo de uma linha.

No PostGIS, séries de pontos podem ser representadas como uma string de pares lat/lon separados por vírgula, e convertidos para tipos de dados de geometria através de [uma função](http://www.postgis.net/docs/ST_GeomFromText.html):

```
select ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(34.295944 132.319809, 34.295971 132.319809, 34.295998 132.320129, 34.296024 132.319763)');
```

Não possuo, entretanto, ambiente PostGIS criado no momento, e imagino que o assunto já fuja um pouco do escopo da pergunta "é possível extrair vértice inicial e final de um vetor com PostgreSQL?". Caso queira saber mais sobre a extensão PostGIS, ela possui [documentação](http://www.postgis.net/documentation/) bem completa, assim como a do próprio PostgreSQL.